# How to fetch rss feeds from website using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, feedjira

I am using `Feedjira` in my application which is an excellent option to get rss feeds and getting all feeds when we provide a valid feed URL. But Now I want to get feeds when I provide website url instead of feed url. Unfortunately, I am not getting valid data using Feedjira.

I have tried with `FeedBag` gem which is working as expected but for some urls it is not working properly. Can anyone please suggest me any gems/plugins to get valid feeds using website url in rails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which website rss feed you want to fetch?

Comment: @puneet18 any kind of website for example: http://allbanglanewspaper.net/item/samakal.html, http://www.thedailystar.net etc.,

Comment: I think Feedbag is good, checked the code there for a bit. It seems that the sites you are trying to fetch don't have proper links to their rss feeds. the first one just has an iframe, so Feedbag can't properly seach for rss feed links in there. and the second example you have as a link to an inner page that shows all feeds. so you can't have a tool that works for every website out there. i would personally stick with adding rss directly instead of hoping a script will actually find those urls

Comment: @Cremz Whatever you said is correct and it is possible with Feedjira when we have direct rss urls. But when we have website urls feedjira is not able to get feeds. and with feedbag all the websites are not working. Please let me know if you find any gem/plugin to get rss feed urls from all the websites.

Comment: @Cremz I have done some customization to the feedbag gem and getting feeds for some of the urls. but for the below url's I didnt see any rss url http://www.bd-pratidin.com/ http://www.newagebd.net etc., can you please suggest me anyway too identify rss feeds for those urls

Comment: i think those 2 sites just don't have an rss feed. if you can't find any link to their rss in the source.. just give up, they probably don't have one

Comment: @Cremz Thank you Cremz.